# Switching solarized colors with mintty and tmux

Tags: colors, tmux, solarized

I am trying to find a way to easily toggle between light/dark solarized themes without needing to create a new terminal/tmux session. I am running mintty on a Windows machine and usually log into a Linux machine and connect to a tmux session.

Using [mavnn's solarized mintty](https://github.com/mavnn/mintty-colors-solarized) colors and [seebi's solarized tmux](https://github.com/seebi/tmux-colors-solarized) colors, I have written some bash functions that can change the terminal colors on the fly. This is in my .bashrc:

```
function godark()
{
    ~/solarized/sol.dark
    tmux source-file ~/tmux/tmuxcolors-dark.conf
}

function golight()
{
    ~/solarized/sol.light
    tmux source-file ~/tmux/tmuxcolors-light.conf
}
```

So inside of sol.dark there are instructions such as:

```
echo -ne '\eP\e]10;#839496\a' # Foreground -> base0
echo -ne '\eP\e]11;#002B36\a' # Background -> base03
```

and inside of my tmuxcolors-dark.conf I'll have things such as:

```
set-option -g status-bg colour235 #base02
set-option -g status-fg colour130 #yellow
```

This is *almost* working. If I do not have tmux open I can type "godark" and mintty will change to a dark theme, but if I type this in tmux, it will change my tmux status bar to the correct theme, but my terminal background does not change color. I do not really understand ANSI escape sequences so maybe I'm doing something silly here. I'd appreciate any help in getting this working!

Comment: Try starting tmux as `tmux -2` to support 256 colors, from inside a terminal set as `screen-256color`. For more info see [this article](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2012/10/17/vim-solarized-and-tmux/).

Comment: Thanks, @harrymc. I did try this and unfortunately it did not help. From what I can tell I have 256 colors working fine, I just cannot switch between light and dark themes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send an escape sequence from inside tmux to the containing terminal by transforming your escape sequence like this:

1. double all occurrences of `\e`
2. prepend `\ePtmux;`
3. append `\e\\`

For example, using [st](http://st.suckless.org/) as my terminal emulator, I can redefine color #1 (red) of its palette by executing

```
printf '\e]4;1;#aa0000\a'
```

To do the same from within tmux, I have to use

```
printf '\ePtmux;\e\e]4;1;#aa0000\a\e\\'
```

When using a shell script/function to switch colors, check for the `$TMUX` environment variable.  If it is not empty, then you are inside tmux.